# IBM websphere scripting with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, websphere

Need to create an automate script with jmeter for sending xml to queue.
We are using IBM websphere mq to put xml to queues.

We have received hostname,port,queue manager and queue name info from application team along with the xml contents.

Found blogs on Google that we can get it done using jms point to point sampler in jmeter.
Since it's a new concept for me so not sure what are the mandatory details that we have to enter in that sampler.

1. Inputs for jms resources- who will provide that.
   2.JNDI properties-initial context factory value.

Any pre-requisite jar or something that we have to install.
Any help on this will be appreciated.
Thanks

I have added jms p2p sampler and provided connection details under jndi properties .

Not sure what value to be put for initial context factory ,jndi name request queue ,receive queue and under queue connection factory parameters.

Is this the right way of handling IBM websphere mqs using jmeter.Using jmeter 5.1 version for testing.

Answer (score 0):

`Any pre-requisite jar or something that we have to install` - yes, as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#lets_start)

> JMeter includes the JMS API jar, but does not include a JMS client implementation. If you want to run JMS tests, you will need to download the appropriate jars from the JMS provider.

for IBMMQ it would be [com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient) which needs to be put into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

With regards to sending the message I believe you should consider using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and writing the code to connect to the queue manager and send the message in Groovy, something like:

```
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants

import javax.jms.Session

def hostName = "your IBMMQ Host"
def hostPort = 1414
def channelName = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN"
def queueManagerName = "QM1"
def queueName = "DEV.QUEUE.1"

def ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER)
def cf = ff.createConnectionFactory()

cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, hostPort)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channelName)
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT)
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManagerName)

def conn = cf.createConnection("app", "test")
def sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)

def destination = sess.createQueue(queueName)

conn.start()

def producer = sess.createProducer(destination)

def rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())

def payload = String.format("JMeter...IBM MQ...test message no. %09d!", rnd.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE))
def msg = sess.createTextMessage(payload)

producer.send(msg)


producer.close()
```

More information: [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how)

Comment: Steps followed:
1. Created a ibmmq folder inside lib folder of jmeter and placed 2 jar files com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.5.0 & Java.jms-api-2.0
2. Modified user.properties file as user.classpath=./lib/activemq;./lib/ibmmq
And restarted jmeter
3.copied your above groovy script by changing my mq details.
Ran jmeter script
Getting error as:
Respone message:
MultiplecompilationErrorsException:startup failed.:
Unable to resolve class both the import classes.
Query:
How to resolve the error?
What details need to be provided under cf.create connection ("app","test") groovy code